# SSAS tabular deploy

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, ssas, tabular

the  visual studio is installed on the local server, however i was asked to deploy SSAS tabular to the server on the cloud, and the result as below :

Error:      Cannot deploy metadata. Reason: An error occurred while connecting to the server.           0

can anyone tell me how to go around it? is it doable?

many thanks in advance

Comment: What is the deployment server set to, and does the account that's being used to deploy it have the proper permissions on the server?

Comment: the visual studio is installed on local machine, while the data  is from cloud and SSAS tabular is deployed to the analysis server that is on the cloud as well. however it propmts the error.  i am not sure whether it is allowed the remote connection and or permission.   if  visual studio is installed on cloud, could it solve the issue? thanks

Answer (score 4):

Change the deployment server name to your SSAS server name as next and then deploy again:
[image: DeploymentServer]