# cannot deploy metadata. reason;an error occurred while connecting to server

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, ssas-tabular, analysisservices

I have made an Analysis service tabular project . now I wanna deploy the project but it gives the error cannot deploy metadata. reason;an error occurred while connecting to server. I checked the ssdt is installed. I don't know what else I have to check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your deployment server is probably set to localhost.
Change this in your Property Page to the correct Server.

More info:[SSAS tabular deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54113987/ssas-tabular-deploy)

Answer (score 1):

Another reason to encounter this error is that the server is utilizing the Multidimensional model (traditional OLAP Cube) instead of the tabular model.

SSAS is available in three modes of installation:

- Tabular
- Multidimensional
- SharePoint

To check which mode of SSAS is installed on your machine, follow the below steps:

1.Open SSMS.
2.In Object Explorer, right-click on the SSAS server you're connected to.
[How to open SSAS server properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVkv6.png)

3.The Mode of Server Name is available in the property window. In this example, SSAS is in Multidimensional mode, so it is showing “Multidimensional”.
[How to check server mode in SSAS server properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34P2w.png)

Tip: For more info on Tabular or Multidimensional models in SQL Server Analysis Services:
https://www.element61.be/en/resource/choice-between-tabular-or-multidimensional-models-sql-server-analysis-services-2012.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error for unknown reason. I got around it by using Analysis Services Deployment Wizard.

The steps are following:

1. Build the model in Visual Studio.
2. Use Analysis Services Deployment Wizard for deployment. Select the "Model.asdatabase" file from "bin" folder of your model project.
3. After deployment run Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), open the Analysis Services connection, expand to your model, and then expand "Connections".
4. On each connection in the list, right click and select "Refresh Credentials". It will ask for the user and password of the data source, similarly like it usually does in Visual Studio during deployment.
5. Right click on the model, select "Process Database". From dropdown select "Full process", and process the model.

Answer (score -1):

Apart from the above solution, there might be a chance that the analysis service is not running. So, check from the configuration manager that your analysis service is running or not.